Is space travel restricted in “Star Trek: Picard” when compared to other interations of the “Star Trek” franchise?
In previous incarnations of Star Trek there was an emphasis on exploration. The cast would frequently leave the Star Trek: The Next Generation Enterprise personal excursions using Federation Shuttles, there were regular shuttles and freighters coming in and out of Star Trek: Deep Space Nine and going to many different worlds as part of the ongoing story about it being a hub for travel and commerce, and all incarnations of the cast would regularly come across everyone form private freighters to personal shuttles. Even in Enterprise some of the crew grew up on early privately owned warp capable ships.
In Star Trek: Picard this aspect of the franchise seems to be downplayed in some episodes and missing in others to the extent that Picard has to resort to personal contacts with a former Starfleet intelligence officer to leave Earth in an unregistered ship when previously he would have taken a standard shuttlecraft or runabout type craft.
Beyond Picard himself, other characters such as Jurati seem to have little or no experience of space travel, or consider space travel to be a big adventure, whereas it was not seen as being remarkable by characters from Star Trek: The Next Generation onwards.
Is this simply due to the different writing style of Star Trek: Picard and it being a non-exploration based series with a different emphasis from previous incarnations, or are there canonical in universe restrictions or similar that make space travel less accessible than during — for example — the time of Star Trek: The Next Generation?

He's retired....

In TNG we see plenty of privately owned shuttles and freighters, in DS9 they have civilian passenger vessels like we have 747. This isn't shown in Picard.

He needs the exclusive use of a fast ship

@Valorum, In TNG those seemed to grow on trees, by the time of Voyager they could be made in industrial replicators.

Roddenberry was very keen that you can't replicate entire ships.

@Valorum, The Delta Flier was replicated in pieces and then assembled in Voyager's hanger. DS9 mentions industrial replicators that could replicate warp capable shuttle craft. There was an episode of Enterprise where they came across a free floating dockyard that could assemble an entire ship from replicated components.

Actually it wasn't. It was constructed out of custom-built parts and various supplies that they either had in storage, or cannibalised from existing shuttlecraft. I'm sure that some bits were replicated, but not the bulk of it.

That episode had an industrial replicator capable, with input from an alien computer using stolen brains(!) to replicate parts, but there's no indication it could replicate a ship, as evidenced by the fact that there was a shopping list of things it needed, in return for carrying out repairs.

@Valorum, I'm thinking the class 4 replicators stolen in Season 4 episode 22 of DS9 which could replicate shuttle craft.

Where does it say that they can replicate shuttlecraft? If memory serves it says something about being used to help fabricate power plants and factories.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7067/20774

@Valorum, superseded by later material, and could we please limit discussions to the original question as I don't want an OT warning.
